# MySQL problema. Can't locate file generated by select into outfile '/tmp/aa.txt'

Tags: mysql, linux, into-outfile

I ran grant file on my user. I'm using absolute path. Mysql user have privileges to write at /tmp. I just can't locate the file. I ran updatedb and then locate aa.txt, with no result.

I'm running:

> select 'aaaaaa' into outfile '/tmp/aa.txt';

Mysql responds: Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

The second time I run the same command, it get's an error:

> ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '/tmp/aauua.txt' already exists

I'm running mysql 5.5.31 on Fedora 18. Does anybody knows what could be wrong?

Comment: Are the client and server the same machine?

Comment: The file is generated in the Server side!

Comment: Client and server are on the same machine.

Comment: Instead of using into outfile, I'm now capturing the output of the mysql client (mysq params params > output.txt). But still, this issue is not solved.

Comment: Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` the file is created on the server host.

If you are aware of that, the problem might be that mysqld is started with systemd and configured to use a private /tmp directory, in that case you'll find it inside /tmp/systemd-namespace-XXXXXX/

See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ServicesPrivateTmp

And you are not finding it with locate, since updatedb doesn't store files located in /tmp.